# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating XYZ)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I cannot seem to shake this error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have a 'show' screen displaying a selected post. At the top of the screen is a profile picture for the user that posted.

When the component is mounted, details of the select post are retrieved and stored in a state ("post"). This post-state includes a user object which contains information about the user that made the post - including, in some cases, their profile picture.

As not all users have profile pictures, I use a simple ternary operator to determine whether a profile picture or an icon should be displayed:

```
 const [post, setPost] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        const post = feed.find(el => el.id === props.route.params.postId)
        setPost(post)
    }, [feed])


return <>
      <ListItem>
          { post.user.profilePic 
                ? <Avatar source={{ uri: post.user.profilePic }} size="medium" rounded />
                : <Avatar rounded icon={{ name: 'person', type: "ionicons" }} size="medium" rounded overlayContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }} />}           
            <ListItem.Content>
                    <ListItem.Title style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{"@" + post.user.userName}</ListItem.Title>
            </ListItem.Content>
        </ListItem>
```

Quite straightforward and this same code works fine in other components, but in this one, it keeps crashing:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'post.user.profilePic')

This error is located at:
    in ShowScreen (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at 
etc
```

I have tried returning a loading component if the post hasn't fully loaded; change the ternary operator to check if post. user.profile pic === undefined; using type and hasOwnProperty methods.

Here is the 'post' as console.logged:

```
Object {
  "caption": "Testing caption
",
  "comments": Array [
    Object {
      "authorId": "vqEzix1k4tQer7wmMG32Fby4KKg1",
      "authorName": "sarah123",
      "comment": "Comments test",
      "created": t {
        "nanoseconds": 119000000,
        "seconds": 1614335984,
      },
      "id": "sYCm2nk0XpDKYiBQ6fmy",
    },
    Object {
      "authorId": "vqEzix1k4tQer7wmMG32Fby4KKg1",
      "authorName": "rob123",
      "comment": "Testing comments works!",
      "created": t {
        "nanoseconds": 362000000,
        "seconds": 1614331033,
      },
      "id": "srd6faF3uw2AvQbWskzd",
    },
  ],
  "creation": t {
    "nanoseconds": 144000000,
    "seconds": 1612301025,
  },
  "currentUserLike": false,
  "downloadUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rn-instagram-clone-88f85.appspot.com/o/post%2F2qZfG0Wve6hmffdS0hL13qoIYp92%2F0.xgqi91loct?alt=media&token=ac9bc56f-d04b-46f2-acc6-45f8475134ab",
  "id": "PiFmGtUb55OMGUiIQO61",
  "location": "Bangor",
  "user": Object {
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "name": "test",
    "uid": "2qZfG0Wve6hmffdS0hL13qoIYp92",
  },
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this a problem but you've defined "const post" twice, once in the hook and the other in "useEffect". Try using a different variable name inside useEffect and see if that helps

Comment: Also try this: setPost(post || {})

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but same error. I don't think the issue is with the useEffect. This code works fine for the rest of the post information, the only problem seems to be with the user object (which is nested within the post)

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the contents of "post"? Just to get an idea of what the data looks like?

Comment: Yes I have added, sorry should have included originally.

Comment: Also to confirm "post" is in JSON form? Not stringified JSON?

Comment: yes its json format

Answer (score 1):

You should update post state when you have found the valid one.

```
 const [post, setPost] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        const post = feed.find(el => el.id === props.route.params.postId)
        if (post) {
          setPost (post)
        }
    }, [feed])


return <>
      <ListItem>
          { post.user.profilePic 
                ? <Avatar source={{ uri: post.user.profilePic }} size="medium" rounded />
                : <Avatar rounded icon={{ name: 'person', type: "ionicons" }} size="medium" rounded overlayContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }} />}           
            <ListItem.Content>
                    <ListItem.Title style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{"@" + post.user.userName}</ListItem.Title>
            </ListItem.Content>
        </ListItem>
```

Comment: Thanks but does not resolve the problem unfortunately. The post definitely exists, because the user is routed to this from a screen showing all posts. Also when I remove the profilePic code it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<ListItem>
  {post && post.user && post.user.profilePic ? (
    <Avatar source={{ uri: post.user.profilePic }} size="medium" rounded />
  ) : (
    <Avatar
      rounded
      icon={{ name: "person", type: "ionicons" }}
      size="medium"
      rounded
      overlayContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "grey" }}
    />
  )}
  <ListItem.Content>
    <ListItem.Title style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
      {post && post.user && post.user.userName ? "@" + post.user.userName :""}
    </ListItem.Title>
  </ListItem.Content>
</ListItem>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use null check post.user && post.user.profilePic
```